# Quickblox - group chat with javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I have been having trouble setting up a groupchat using QB Javascript SDK.

A couple of issues:
First, I keep getting "room is locked" message https://i.stack.imgur.com/auR21.png
Not sure why, the server side, the room is setup as public group and not a private chat.

Secondly, it looks like only one user can login. 
- I login with user "John" - it throws the message about "room is locked" but logs in and works fine. 
- I login with another user "Doe", in a different browser or device, it logs in but there are no events fired.
- If i logout both and try to login "doe", it works.

I could only come to the conclusion that only one user works at a time for starter version? Can someone clarify this to me?

My code is heavily borrowed from http://quickblox.github.io/sample-chat-xmpp-web/examples/groupchat.html. The only difference is obviously the appid and its settings (yes some custom events, but the core is same).

this can be accessed here: http://arrayinfinite.info/veeru/demo.php

I login as John, i see this -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDPN.png

If, i login as doe right after that, i only see a message "doe has logged in" - but nothing works.

If i logout both, and login only doe, it works - Logging in with john does'nt work at that point.

Anybody can guide me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the old and deprecated chat sample.
We have published new version of JS SDK which doesn't need any additional plugins.

Download the latest version:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript

Unfortunately, we don't have the updated sample yet. But you can use these code snippets:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Chat_2.0_API_instead_the_chat_plugin

and this example for creating the group chat:
https://gist.github.com/AndreyPovelichenko/37e40b338279f59b3fbd